# Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm starting to develop in PHP and I'm using [this guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/) to get me started.

The issue I'm facing is that I cannot log into MySQL (using phpMyAdmin). After reading some questions I tries to change the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` but this didn't solve the issue.

This is the contents of the `config.inc.php` file

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `['auth_type'] = 'cookie'` you need to enter the `mysql` `username` and `password`.

[This guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/#mysql) from the same site your following might be helpful although its using Mac OS Yosimite.